# Regex in a line to be replaced

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, replace

I need to replace this line and write it in a new text file.

```
Material(j)..              sum(l$downstream_rm(j,l),Rin(j,l))=e=25;
```

I have a String str with numeric values. I need to replace 25 with the string's value.
Also I have another String mstr which will either contain "e" or "m" or "l" and I need to replace these with the existing e of the line . With what regex could I do that in the same time?

Comment: You "need to replace 25 with the string's value" and you say before that that the string has numeric **values**. Which value are you going to replace? And that's not the only weird part of your question. You would probably be better off with examples of what you have and what should be the result.

Comment: Replace "25" with a String str and "e" with another String mstr @Jerry

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Eclipse (using search) or with Java code? If the latter, the [tag:eclipse] tag is not really appropriate. And have you tried to solve this problem yourself? If so, can you show us some of your code? If you haven't, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "Material(j)..      sum(l$downstream_rm(j,l),Rin(j,l))=e=25;";
    System.out.println(str.matches("^Material\\(j\\).*sum\\(l\\$downstream_rm\\(j,l\\),Rin\\(j,l\\)\\)=e=25;$"));
```

**OUTPUT:**
true

After you've found that the line matches - it's easy enough to replace the `e=25` part with anything you want:

```
str = str.replace("e=25", mstr+"="+e);
```